# JVMCrash on 1.8.172 + itext7.0.5 + linux + centos + AWS EC2-M5 - XLARGE

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, itext, centos7

we are using itext 7.0.5 for one editing pdfs. when we try to save pdf, JVM is getting crashed. is this a known issue? issue is more frequent, i would not say it is consistent, but it is more frequent that to be inconsistent. below is the crash report.

or as @Bruno Lowagie  mentioned, could it be a hardware issue? any quick help appreciated...

```
Stack: [0x00007f89d4dd1000,0x00007f89d4ed2000],  sp=0x00007f89d4ecd768,  free space=1009k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
C  [libc.so.6+0x159990]  __memmove_ssse3_back+0x50
J 4377  sun.misc.Unsafe.copyMemory(Ljava/lang/Object;JLjava/lang/Object;JJ)V (0 bytes) @ 0x00007f89f5e87761 [0x00007f89f5e87680+0xe1]
J 18168 C1 java.nio.Bits.copyToArray(JLjava/lang/Object;JJJ)V (68 bytes) @ 0x00007f89f810ff6c [0x00007f89f810fec0+0xac]
J 22335 C1 java.nio.DirectByteBuffer.get([BII)Ljava/nio/ByteBuffer; (126 bytes) @ 0x00007f89f8c6b7f4 [0x00007f89f8c6b460+0x394]
j  com.itextpdf.io.source.ByteBufferRandomAccessSource.get(J[BII)I+66
j  com.itextpdf.io.source.MappedChannelRandomAccessSource.get(J[BII)I+27
j  com.itextpdf.io.source.FileChannelRandomAccessSource.get(J[BII)I+10
J 20012 C2 com.itextpdf.io.source.RandomAccessFileOrArray.read()I (42 bytes) @ 0x00007f89f5b213fc [0x00007f89f5b21300+0xfc]
J 19982 C1 com.itextpdf.io.source.PdfTokenizer.read()I (8 bytes) @ 0x00007f89f77d30c4 [0x00007f89f77d3040+0x84]
j  com.itextpdf.io.source.PdfTokenizer.readString(I)Ljava/lang/String;+16
j  com.itextpdf.io.source.PdfTokenizer.getStartxref()J+46
j  com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfReader.readXref()V+8
j  com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfReader.readPdf()V+32
j  com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfDocument.open(Lcom/itextpdf/kernel/pdf/PdfVersion;)V+30
j  com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfDocument.<init>(Lcom/itextpdf/kernel/pdf/PdfReader;Lcom/itextpdf/kernel/pdf/PdfWriter;Lcom/itextpdf/kernel/pdf/StampingProperties;)V+287
j  com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfDocument.<init>(Lcom/itextpdf/kernel/pdf/PdfReader;Lcom/itextpdf/kernel/pdf/PdfWriter;)V+10
```

Comment: It's not a known issue, and it looks more like a random file access / memory problem than an actual iText problem. I think the problem would also occur when trying to perform random access on a large file without involving iText.

Comment: is there any workaround for this? are you saying, since it is a java issue, we can not use the api of itext also?

Comment: I don't know. I can't reproduce it. The only time I had a similar problem, was on a machine that had a mechanical defect. In that case, it was a hardware error that made the machine crash each time a specific memory address was accessed. That made the problem impossible to "debug" because one couldn't predict when the faulty memory was accessed. The problem was completely erratic and not reproducible on another machine. We ended up replacing the machine.